# Changing name of item in separate column in query to make grouping easier

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the full inventory for certain sellers. However, I'm having a problem grouping info together based on two separate columns. For every item listed there's the "seller" column and there's an "inferred_seller" column where the product's original company can be listed (think if Kirkland Products from Costco were being sold in Tesco markets in England). I want to calculate the full items altogether for the main clients.

```
Sample Data:

ID    seller      item     inferred_seller
1     Store_A     Chips     Store_A
2     Store_B     Donuts    NULL
3     Store_C     Crackers  NULL
4     Store_D     Chicken   Store_B
5     Store_D     Soup      Store_C
6     Store_E     Apple     Store_C
7     Store_E     Plum      Store_B
8     Store_E     Bread     Store_A
```

What I've been trying already is Case When scenarios to Alias the seller listing as the inferred_seller so that I can add them together.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C') THEN 
seller WHEN inferred_seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C') THEN 
inferred_seller = seller END AS seller's, count(id)
FROM items
WHERE seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C') OR 
inferred_seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C')
GROUP BY 1
```

Currently this just spits out just the info from the seller column while the inferred part is put into a NULL or 0 grouping. What I want it to show is Store A is made up from seller + inferred_seller (if already not under seller).

Ideally, the results will just show something like this:

```
Sellers   count(id)
Store_A     2
Store_B     3
Store_C     3
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION to return a dataset with both fields combined into one column:

```
SELECT
    Seller, 
    COUNT(id)
FROM (
    SELECT
        Id,
        Seller
    FROM items
    WHERE Seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Id,
        Inferred_Seller
    FROM items
    WHERE Inferred_Seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C')
    )    
GROUP BY Seller
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns all the other sellers that I don't want. I only want those 3 sellers, but the query returns over 2000.

Comment: That's rather odd considering that there's a WHERE statement to limit the query to those three sellers.

Comment: The problem is that an inferred seller can still have a separate store so its showing me all those other stores since it still meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you'd just need something like:

```
CASE 
   WHEN seller NOT IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C') THEN inferred_seller 
   ELSE seller 
END AS seller
....
WHERE seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C') 
   OR inferred_seller IN ('Store_A','Store_B','Store_C')
```

Comment: This is actually very helpful, but I'm now getting the sellers + a Null grouping even with the specification. I don't understand where the Null grouping is coming from as those results should be spread into the other seller groupings.

Comment: Since your sample data indicates `seller` is never null, it must be coming from the `inferred_seller` field; but the only null `inferred_sellers` fields should be ignored since their `seller` is in the list. Are you sure there are not spaces or non-printing characters in the `seller` field's values? You should be able to add `GROUP_CONCAT(ID)` to the select list to see where the nulls are coming from better.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to a colleague, the answer is that I needed to plug in COALESCE (inferred_seller, seller) in the SELECT statement and the WHERE statement to give what I wanted.  Thanks for everyones help!